# Trouble making android apps work for tablets

Tags: android

I've got someone who wants to download an app to their Xoom, but when they go to download it, it says that the app is limitted to phones only.  The android market settings say that the app is supported by the Xoom though, so I'm at a bit of a loss.  Could this be a coding issue? The app was originally designed for API level 8, but  I'd think it should be forward compatible...  Xlarge screens are supported, as are all densities, but the Xoom still says that it can't download the app...

Anyone know what's going on here?
Thanks!

Here's the manifest up to activities:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        package="com.bjpcomet.XCScore" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk 
            android:minSdkVersion="1" 
            android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
    <application 
            android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:debuggable="false">
    <activity 
            android:name="com.bjpcomet.XCScore.ScoringApp" 
            android:label="@string/main_title">
```

Comment: post your manifest we'll try to find out the issue. you can cut away all the activities, etc

Comment: Assuming that the app you're referring to is "Cross Country Scorekeeper", I was able to download it from the Android Market and run it just fine on my Xoom from Verizon.

Comment: that IS strange... this is what I'm hearing from the guy I've been talking to: "The error is simply a grey box that says Your device is not compatible with this item. This is a pop up i get when I click the buy button."  I'll ask him to recheck it one more time, but I expect the same result...

Answer (score 0):

When you create the project you have to choose the build target as the tablet add-on, as in my case it was GALAXY Tab Addon, the platform os 2.2 only but my app works fine on tablets.

At the time of project creation when you select the build target it is saved in the **default.properties** in your project. You can have a look at your default.properties this is an auto generated file there is a line like

```
# Project target.
target=Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.:GALAXY Tab Addon:8
```

in your case it would be

```
# Project target.
target=android-8
```

So to make your project work on the tablets as well as phones you have to use some tablet addon as build target with the platform os of your choice

**Added**

1. No. there cannot be multiple build targets.
2. try making an app with GALAXY Tab Addon. hopefully it will work on Xoom.
3. when you make a an app with a lower os platform it runs on the latest versions also but if you make an app with like 3.1 then that app will not work on lower versions

just give it a try i haven't used XOOM but am preety much sure this will work out and also there are few more addons like by SonyEricsson, LG and Kyocera you can just make small apps and can check them if they work or not

But first try it with the Galaxy Addon

:)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at least now I sort of understand what's going on! (you'll have to forgive me, I'm pretty new at this)

Can there be multiple build targets? (I'm guessing no) The way you explained it makes it sound like I would have to create an individual app for ever different tablet out there... Is there any way to easily make the app compatible with most/all tablets in one go? Will the tablet-friendly app still be phone-compatible as well?

(specifically, my current customer has a Xoom running honeycomb 3.1, but a general solution would be much more useful than a specific one!)

Comment: Alright, I'll try the galaxy tab addon!  You say that crossing from 2.x to 3.x will cause compatibility issues though?  That may be the problem, since the xoom is running 3.1...

Comment: Alright, the galaxy addon seems to make the app run on the xoom emulator (didn't run with the old setup, so that's good news!)